# Post microphone input from Flash to server

Tags: flash, post, save, microphone

We're trying to get microphone input in a Flash movie and the post it to the server so it can be saved in a file.

Currently, we're using PHP in the server, but I guess the key thing here is: **How to post the audio to the server?**

After a post is made, then I guess it'd be a matter of handling the encoding and saving to a file, which can be done with pretty much any server-side language.

Any idea if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a streaming server is your best bet, something like FMS or Red5.

There are a couple of transcoders from WAV to MP3, this being an example: http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/

All the examples I could find of encoding on the client use Alchemy, which leverages C or C++ code and compiles it into your swf, if this sounds like fun to you good luck, otherwise I'd look at the server options I mentioned first.